# Why won't jQuery show my hidden content?

Tags: php, jquery, show

I'm trying to have jQuery .show(); my content, but it never shows it! I checked the syntax, ad it all seems fine. Can anybody help me?

The URL of the content is http://craigslistcloud.com/

When you click Login it should show the class, .loginform-nav

Thanks!

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null`

Comment: Please post actual code (HTML of what you want show, jQuery of how you're attempting to show it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url to the jQuery script (http://craigslistcloud.com/uploadify/jquery-1.4.2.min.js) is returning a 404. Which is why you are getting the error:

```
$(document).ready is not a function
```

Fix this and it should work.

Comment: I think prototype's `$` is kicking in there, which is why `ready` is not a function rather than `$` ;)

Comment: Yeah, it's loaded, but it's version 1.3.2. Type jQuery into the console, and you'll see the function.

Comment: ahhh. didnt see it. i guess it is just a mess in there :)

Comment: Actually it's jQuery 1.5. The filename is 1.3.2, but if you type `jQuery.fn.jquery`, it shows that the content is actually 1.5.

Comment: When I removed the script that was returning the 404 it all worked.

Answer (score 2):

You have both `jQuery` and `prototypejs` loaded.

I'd suggest using one or the other. If that's not a possibility, then call `jQuery.noConflict()`, and replace your jQuery use of `$` with `jQuery`, or some replacement you define.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j('#custom_file_upload').uploadify({
        'uploader': '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script': '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
        'cancelImg': '/uploadify/cancel.png',
        'queueID': 'fileQueue',
        'folder': '/uploads',
        'multi': true,
        'auto': true,
        onComplete: function (event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
            $j('#links').append('&lt;img src="http://craigslistcloud.com' + encodeURI(response) + '" align="center" /&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;<br><br>');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Two immediate problems:

1. You have the script that binds the click handler before the actual element. It can't find the element unless you either place the `<script>` after the `<a id="Login">` or you wrap the code inside a `$(function () { });`.
2. You have jQuery 1.3.2, jQuery 1.4.2 **and** prototype loaded on the same page. You will have conflicts. You need to remove one of the jQuery scripts and use `jQuery.noConflict()` or just always use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Comment: +1 Good catch on the link binding. I didn't see that. Everything's sort of spread out on that page.